# How to connect sqlite in xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-sqlite, sqlite-net

I am trying to connect to the DB(SQlite) but I keep on getting an error.

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not resolve type with token 01000150 from typeref (expected class 'SQLite.CreateTableResult' in assembly 'SQLite-net, Version=1.7.335.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null')'

And my code to connect is:

```
this.db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath, storeDateTimeAsTicks: true);
this.db.CreateTableAsync<User>().Wait();
```

Any suggestion how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is diferent for us to reproduce this problem only based on the error log you posted, but you can refer to official document [Xamarin.Forms Local Databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases).

And there is an good sample included in above document , which code is well encapsulated and very concise. You can check it here [Todo](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/Todo) .

The `TodoItemDatabase.cs` is as follows:

```
public class TodoItemDatabase
{
    static SQLiteAsyncConnection Database;

    public static readonly AsyncLazy<TodoItemDatabase> Instance = new AsyncLazy<TodoItemDatabase>(async () =>
    {
        var instance = new TodoItemDatabase();
        CreateTableResult result = await Database.CreateTableAsync<TodoItem>();
        return instance;
    });

    public TodoItemDatabase()
    {
        Database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.DatabasePath, Constants.Flags);
    }

    public Task<List<TodoItem>> GetItemsAsync()
    {            
        return Database.Table<TodoItem>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public Task<List<TodoItem>> GetItemsNotDoneAsync()
    {
        return Database.QueryAsync<TodoItem>("SELECT * FROM [TodoItem] WHERE [Done] = 0");
    }

    public Task<TodoItem> GetItemAsync(int id)
    {
        return Database.Table<TodoItem>().Where(i => i.ID == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public Task<int> SaveItemAsync(TodoItem item)
    {
        if (item.ID != 0)
        {
            return Database.UpdateAsync(item);
        }
        else
        {
            return Database.InsertAsync(item);
        }
    }

    public Task<int> DeleteItemAsync(TodoItem item)
    {
        return Database.DeleteAsync(item);
    }
}
```